# How to check particular custom option exists or not?

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, custom-options, magento-1

I need to put a check whether the product have the particular custom option or not?

I have product ID and the custom option title is Custom Size now I want to check that for the product with this I'd have any custom option with title size or not.

I hope anyone came across this.

Answer (score 6):

You could load the options collection and filter by product id and title.

```
$options = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addTitleToResult(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addPriceToResult(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addProductToFilter(array('product_id'))
    ->addValuesToResult()
    ->addFieldToFilter('default_option_title.title', 'Option title');
```

With the title there is a default option and also a store title so you should us either of the following lines.

```
->addFieldToFilter('default_option_title.title', 'Option title')
->addFieldToFilter('store_option_title.title', 'Option title')
```

Comment: ,good work..it is good logic,i  have give you upvote

Comment: @David, is it feasible to filter by 'title'?

Answer (score 1):

If by custom option you mean a product attribute, you could simply define a function in your helper like this

```
public function isCustomSize($product) 
    {
        $attributeSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set");
        $attributeSetModel->load($product->getAttributeSetId());
        $attributeSetName  = $attributeSetModel->getAttributeSetName();

        if($attributeSetName == 'Custom Size')
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

> EDIT:

To check the the product option

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

if ($product->hasOptions()) {
    foreach ($product->getOptions() as $option) {
        if ($option->getTitle() === 'Custom Size') {
            echo 'Product '. $product->getName() . ' has a custom size option!';
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't think he means 'Product attribute' by 'custom option'. I think he means this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/create-custom-variants-and-options-of-a-product.

Comment: Yes Marius you are right i exactly mean this.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I'll try to edit it as soon as i have time

Answer (score 1):

I have tried things but as it was very urgent, i did it with a code patch. i would like to share it.

```
$product_has_size = 0; 
foreach ($productCollection->getOptions() as $value) { 
if ( $value->getTitle() == 'Size' ) {   $product_has_size = 1;  }
}

/* Value 0 of this variable states that the product doesn't have size option. and 1 means it has the size option. */
```

Answer (score 0):

use the method 
$product->getHasOptions()